# Не собирается артифакт многомодульного webapp

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, maven, spring-security

Фрагмент стэк-трейса

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect
>   annotated methods on class com.config.ApplicationContextConfig    at
>   org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:168)
>     ... 54 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/services/OrderService     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)   at
>   org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152)
>     ... 58 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.services.OrderService     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
>     ... 62 more мая 23, 2017 3:23:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: One or
>   more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
>   appropriate container log file мая 23, 2017 3:23:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
>   [] startup failed due to previous errors [2017-05-23 03:23:16,654]
>   Artifact webb:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See
>   server log for details.

Comment: кажется, зависимости забыли в lib положить

Comment: etki, Спасибо!!!